# SVN export is sometimes returning error E160013 "path not found"

Tags: svn

Using svn.exe export for a an old revision where the filepath has since changed - I get E160013 "path not found" - yet I can clearly see the file at its old path when I use Tortoise repo-browser to that old revision.

How can I use the command line to export files from old revisions where the path has since changed ?

Answer (score 6):

Did you use `svn export -r<RRR> <url>`? Use `svn export <url>@<RRR>` instead.

Comment: Geeze.  This was killing me.  The @<RRR> does work.  Feels like a bug (that I cannot use -r or --revision with the correct number).  Thanks cxxl.  Upvote.

Comment: svn: E160013:  path not found